# Transform my Thread code to Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I want to upgrade my code replacing Thread with Task. Considering the example below:

```
new Thread(()=>{
  ...
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
  ...
}
```

After introducing Task:

```
Task.Run(async ()=> {
  ...
  await Task.Delay(5000);
  ...
 }
```

However, this new lambda will swallow the exceptions. I want to preserve the exception handling mechanism. Can you offer a better transformation?

Comment: What do you mean by silence the exceptions? Exceptions will continue to exist, only the way you deal with them will be different, nothing will disappear.

Comment: **unclear what you're asking** 
*Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*

Answer (score 2):

That code will *not* swallow any exceptions.  Any uncaught exceptions thrown from within that lambda will result in setting the exception of the task returned from `Task.Run`.  You can add continuations to that task to handle those exceptions, or if you `await` the task then the exceptions will be automatically re-thrown within the continuation added.

Answer (score 0):

You should either await the task:

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(5000);
                            throw new Exception("Test1");
                        });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Or use a continuation task that is triggered *only* when the task throws an exception, and let the continuation task handle that exception:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    throw new Exception("Test1");
}).ContinueWith(task =>
                    {
                        foreach (var ex in task.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)
                        {
                                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);    
                        }
                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

**edit**
updated with the correct way of handling exceptions thrown by tasks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When you await a task it unwraps the aggregate exception, it doesn't throw an aggregate exception.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, that makes sense! That explains the results I was getting...